# Закраска ячеек в excel

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь задать программно в excel чтобы если в ячейке было значение больше `0,4`, то цвет данных ячеек был бы зеленый, до `-0,3` -  серый, а еще меньше - красный?

Answer (score 3):

Выбираете нужные ячейки и на главной вкладке нажимаете `Условное форматирование`, затем `Управление правилами`.

Нажимаете `Создать правило`. Далее выбираете `Форматировать только ячейки, которые содержат`, после чего задаете `Значение ячейки`, `больше`, `0,4`, нажимаете кнопку `Формат`, выбираете красный цвет. Далее `ОК`, и еще раз `ОК`.

Таким же образом создаете ещё два правила, но с другими условиями и цветом.

В итоге должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если у меня такая таблица ограмущая че мне каждое число отмечать??нет локаничней варианта?

Comment: @nnnn сначала выбираете все нужные ячейки, затем нажимаете `Условное форматирование`, создаете правила и т.д. они будет применены ко всем выделенным ячейкам.

Comment: @ Vladimir Gamalian Не это я понял,но вопрос состоит теперь в другом. Допустим у меня огромная таблица таких числе и пока я выделю все ячейки пройдет часа 2 нет ли варианта задать нижний порог и от этого порога и выше будет 1 цвет?

Comment: @nnnn там же, где создаются правила (в диспетчере правил условного форматирования) можно задать ячейки в столбике `Применяются к` в виде excel-диапазона (например `=$B$1:$L$18`).

Answer (score 1):

Можно макросцем устанавливать цвет (задаем область, где `r` - количество строк, `c` - количество столбцов):

```
Sub FillCell()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = WB.ActiveSheet

    Dim Cell As Object

    Dim r, c As Integer

    ' Row count
    r = 5
    ' Column count
    c = 4

    For i = 1 To r
        For j = 1 To c
            Set Cell = WS.Cells(i, j)
            If (Cell <> "") And (IsNumeric(Cell)) Then
                With Cell.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

                    Select Case Cell
                        Case Is > 0.4
                            .Color = 65280
                        Case Is > -0.3 <= 0.4
                            .Color = 255
                        Case Else
                            .Color = 12632256
                    End Select

                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]